# Make list of inline nav items the full height of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using an inline list as a nav menu, and I would like the hyperlink/list item to take up the full height of the container with the label vertically positioned in the center of the container. Here is what I have:

```css
#top-nav-container {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  background: #3498db;
}
#top-nav-container .nav-contents {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
#top-nav-container .nav-left {
  width: 175px;
}
#top-nav-container .nav-mid {} #top-nav-container .nav-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
  width: 250px;
}
#top-nav-container .top-nav-logo {
  max-height: 35px;
  float: left;
}
#top-nav-container ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  /* Removes whitespace between li elements */
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
#top-nav-container ul li {} #top-nav-container li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<header id="top-nav-container">

  <div class="container nav-contents">

    <div class="nav-left">
      <a href="#" title="Home">
        <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="Home" class="top-nav-logo" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-mid">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="nav-right">
      Stuff here...
    </div>

  </div>

</header>
```

Any other suggestions you have with any of this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the `line-height` equals the `height` of the container. `display: flex; /* Removes whitespace between li elements */` to remove the white-space my preferred method would be to set `font-size: 0;` on the `ul` and then set it to whatever you want on the `li` (which I've been using for years now in professional frontend development and which has never failed me).

Comment: @connexo I heard the `font-size: 0;` doesn't work well on android devices.

Comment: Well I assume there would have been complaints in the past five years if that were true. None so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both height and line-height to the links, and also make sure they are either `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. Note that `inline-block` would be preferred:

```
#top-nav-container li a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that on small screens, the `Stuff Here...` div would get cut off due to having a current width of 250px. Simply turn this down to say 50px (or however wide your container would actually be):

```
#top-nav-container .nav-right {
    width: 50px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/va1ka281/1/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: There was a `div` with class `nav-right` containing: `Stuff here...` that is not showing any more!

Comment: `display: block;` is only advisable in conjunction with `float: left;` which in return requires some sort of clearing and thus is, imo, the inferior solution compared to `inline-block`.

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni -- I didn't spot this at first due to it only happening on small widths. Simply turn the `width` of down `#top-nav-container .nav-right` down to like `50px` and it works fine :)

Comment: @connexo -- I've updated my answer to recommend that instead :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you. I am using media queries for smaller widths, so that's not a problem. Your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `CSS` a little, see the following snippet:

```css
#top-nav-container {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  background: #3498db;
}
#top-nav-container .nav-contents {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
#top-nav-container .nav-left {
  width: 175px;
}
#top-nav-container .nav-mid {
  /* all below rules were added*/
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#top-nav-container .nav-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
  width: 250px;
}
#top-nav-container .top-nav-logo {
  max-height: 35px;
  float: left;
}
#top-nav-container ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  /* Removes whitespace between li elements */
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
#top-nav-container ul li {} #top-nav-container li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 12px;
  /* all below rules were added*/
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header id="top-nav-container">

  <div class="container nav-contents">

    <div class="nav-left">
      <a href="#" title="Home">
        <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" alt="Home" class="top-nav-logo" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-mid">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="nav-right">
      Stuff here...
    </div>

  </div>

</header>
```